# Transform locks cannot be applied with keyframes

Tags: physics, transforms, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm playing around with physics and rigid bodies and I'm trying to make the cube bounce and slide inside a room with rotating walls. Unfortunately, these doesn't work very well.

As the cube falls and hits the second inclined block, the cube bounces out of the block and falls, so I tried keyframing transform locks so it doesn't rotate in the y and z axis (and the cube wont bounce outside) before it goes inside the room, but the problem is, the transform locks can't be unlocked, and the cube rotation stays in x axis only.

[image]

Is there a way to use a transform locks with keyframes?
OR
Is there another way so that the cube bounces properly?

Also: I'm using blender 2.76.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Try to do this with Rigid Body Constraints. You should be able to animate the Enable property.